# hudson: how to POST this xml following a successful post?

Tags: php, post, hudson

I used Poster addon for firefox to send an xml POST. This is the HTTP Header captured from a successful POST to hudson server. I am trying to replicate this in php using header() function.

```
POST /createItem?name=tellme HTTP/1.1
Host: somewhere.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 715
Cookie: JSESSIONID=69b4cb38635ae490d357bb6b21372507
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers class="vector"/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command></command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers>
    <hudson.plugins.xvnc.Xvnc>
      <takeScreenshot>false</takeScreenshot>
    </hudson.plugins.xvnc.Xvnc>
  </buildWrappers>
</project>
```

Here's my php code:

```
<?php


$data = file_get_contents("config.xml");

$post_data = $data;
$content_length = strlen($post_data);

header('POST /createItem?name=friends HTTP/1.1');
header('Host: somewhere.com');
header('Keep-Alive: 115');
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-length: ' . trim($content_length));
header($post_data);

exit();
```

The php code fails and throws: `Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected. Line 18.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform a post use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $yourPostUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// put your headers here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)', 
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 
'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $yourXML);

echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```